# Prevention of JSON Injection in C#

Tags: c#, json, code-injection

I have following code. In Fortify scan we found there is security flaw in this code. It is prone to JSON Injection. How can we validate JSON string

```
public ActionResult CreateUser(string createUserModel)
{
    User model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(createUserModel);
```

Comment: Validate the string against the JSON schema you expect? Um... JSON has something like Schema language, right? Does it? Hm...

Comment: your json schema can change the validation method. Maybe you can tell us what User is

Answer (score 0):

Validate **User** model afterwards or pass **UserModel** as a parameter to **CreateUser** action and take benefit from classic validation of the framework you are using (is it ASP.NET MVC?).